# Can Qt restrict me from commercial deployment of my application on free license?

Tags: qt

Can they restrict me from commercial deployment of my application ?

If they can then can you please suggest me anyother way to create GUI applications in C++.

**EDIT : Thanks for those answers; BTW is there any other way to make GUI applications in c++ ?**

Comment: Whyy don't you ask the Qt people?

Comment: SO does not give legal advice.  Much of "Qt" is available both under LGPL and a Qt commercial license.  Both restrict what you can do with the code and derivative products in different ways.

Comment: This site is not about legal questions. On a side note, you theoretically should be OK as long as you abide to LGPL, but if you are a cow worth milking, there is no guarantee you are safe. If you are going to make millions, it would be better to buy a commercial license and with it peace of mind.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because itnis seeking Legal Advice.

Comment: Best answered buy reading the QT licensing options: https://www.qt.io/licensing-comparison/

Comment: @user4581301 - actually their official legal FAQ is a sneaky mess. There are numerous vague threats related to making money on an open source license to encourage the purchase of the overpriced commercial license. Also, it is `Qt` not `QT` and `by` not `buy` ;) They also have a video that is just as bad plus featuring a rather unpleasant looking fella.

Comment: Why'd they try to do it anyway? If you link your code statically with Qt and don't tell anyone you're using it, they'd have to first get to _know_ about your app and about your usage of their product in it and then _make sure_ you actually do (so, they'd probably have to try to decompile/debug your app and stuff, which is tricky). Then, they'd have to contact you somehow and so on. This is not so easy to do, so why would they do it?

Comment: If you are distributing a non-open source product using Qt without a commercial license, they are legally in their right to go after you. 
 Here's my advice.  If your product is free, why not make it open source?  If you have a business objective with this product, then just pay for the commercial license.

Comment: @selbie - that is completely wrong. LGPL permits closed source commercial software. The only obligation is that the end user should be able to relink the application. So you either must use dynamic linking or distribute object files for static linking.

Comment: Hate to rain on anyone's parade, but any major library has easter eggs for licensing compliance verification that enable anyone who knows them to trivially uncover presence of their code using keyboard and sometimes mouse. Not having them would amount to negligence. **Any Qt application, past or present, requires only a few input events to detect presence of Qt**. Yes, the code is well hidden. The previous generation easter egg has been publicly disclosed but I don't have the link handy.

Comment: See e.g [this presentation](https://www.kdab.com/wp-content/uploads/stories/slides/DD12/Qt_Surprises.pdf). Note to the unwary: these things have a tendency to be discovered at trade shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt is primarily licensed under the LGPL license, which entitles you generally to share either your source code or the necessary parts of your code that makes the end user able to recompile your code (such as object files of your shared libraries). Some parts of Qt are GPL, which forces you to share the source code when you distribute your software. GPL forces you also to relicense your code as GPL, which is why it's not practical commercially. But LGPL, some companies can live with that.

Whether it's commercial or not commercial is not what GPL/LPGL is about. It's about whether you're forced to share source code with end users.

PS: I'm not a lawyer, so don't hold me liable. You have to [read yourself and learn more about GPL/LGPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.en.html).

Comment: You should refrain from posting answers to offtopic questions.

Comment: @dtech I don't know what to say. I want to help.

Comment: A comment usually suffices. However ultra conservative hardliners would argue that even comment help on offtopic questions is bad. I beg to differ. A comment is a good balance between helping and discouraging offttopic.

Comment: @dtech I expected my answer is going to be long. Usually I just leave a comment.